# Lookup in second table but exclude users from first

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called `permissions` that I'm joining with another collection called `groups`.

`permissions`

```
[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "resource": "resource:docs/61",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "permission": "role:documentOwner",
          "users": [
            "user:def",
            "group:abc",
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.read",
          "users": [
            "user:abc",
            "user:xxx",
            "group:abc"
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.update",
          "users": [
            "user:xxx"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "resource": "resource:docs/38",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "permission": "role:documentOwner",
          "users": [
            "user:abc",
            "user:def",
            "group:abc",
            "group:bff"
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.read",
          "users": [
            "user:xxx"
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.update",
          "users": [
            "user:xxx"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

`groups`

```
[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "id": "abc",
      "name": "Test Group",
      "users": [
        "abc",
        "cpo",
        "yyy",
        "xxx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "id": "bff",
      "name": "Something",
      "users": [
        "xxx"
      ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to do two things:

1. Get all permissions and have any entries in the `users` array that are prefixed with `group:` resolved so that the respective group's users are included in the `users` array.
2. If a permission document has a user that is listed specifically and also contained in a listed group, then that user is not included from the group. In other words, permissions that are granted to a group's users, can be overridden for a member of the group if they are specifically granted permissions. For instance, I grant `group:abc` with `document.read` permission on a resource, but I want `user:abc` (which is a part of the group) to have `document.read` and `document.update` for that resource, so I specifically grant `user:abc` with those permissions.

For example, here's what `permissions._id = 1` would look like...

```
[
{
  "_id": 1,
  "resource": "resource:docs/61",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permission": "role:documentOwner",
      "users": [
        "user:def",
        "user:cpo", // inherited from group:abc
        "user:yyy", // inherited from group:abc
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission": "document.read",
      "users": [
        "user:abc", // not inherited even though part of group:abc because they're specifically listed in the original document
        "user:xxx", // not inherited even though part of group:abc because they're specifically listed in the original document
        "user:cpo", // inherited from group:abc
        "user:yyy", // inherited from group:abc
      ]
    },
    {
      "permission": "document.update",
      "users": [
        "user:xxx" // not inherited even though part of group:abc because they're specifically listed in the original document
      ]
    }
  ]
},
...
]
```

I created a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZwLysAqitkB) to use for testing. I'm failing miserably though

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think I have seen this schema sometimes ago in another question, which was a pain to work with. A schema like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nan8XEGKoB8) would be much more sensible.

Comment: Hi @ray . You're probably referring to another question that I asked a couple months ago. One that you undoubtedly answered. I like the idea of changing the schema - it wouldn't be too much work - however it doesn't solve the issue of my original question... overriding group permissions on a resource for a specific user.

Comment: A group could be assigned `read` but maybe there's a user that's in that group that you want to give `update` permission to for a specific resource. This gives the ability to apply permissions in a generic way but then assign more specific permissions in certain scenarios. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, all good points, and I'm grateful for the schema change suggestions. I'll look into that.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thank you. You may want to reference my proposed schema to separate permissions into individual documents so the logic can be kind of "worked" around since permissions are not bound together for the same resource.

Comment: What do you mean by "bound together"? A resource can have any number of CRUD permissions assigned to any number of users/groups.

Comment: "bound together" means the permissions are put together for a single resource in your current schema. This might create a bloated document. What I am understanding is that you are mostly working on permission level(i.e. most of the time you are working on a single permission for a single resource), so that might be better if you put it in individual documents such that you can easier process them. Potentially you can also index the permission documents to improve performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. reserve an array of users of other permissions(named `otherPermissions`) for later filtering
2. `$unwind` to process at permission-resource level
3. "split" the `users` array into "user" and "groups" respectively. Locate the array entries using `$indexOfCP` equal to 0 to check for the prefix.
4. `$lookup` to the `groups` collection
5. perform `$setUnion` to union the permissions for individual users and permissions granted from groups; prune the users in looked up group users if they are in `otherPermissions`
6. `$group` again to get back original form

```js
db.permissions.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "permissions": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$permissions",
          "as": "p",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$p",
              {
                otherPermissions: {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$permissions",
                    "as": "otherPermissions",
                    "cond": {
                      $ne: [
                        "$$otherPermissions.permission",
                        "$$p.permission"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$permissions"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      // process users entries
      users: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$permissions.users",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  0,
                  {
                    "$indexOfCP": [
                      "$$this",
                      "user:"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      "$replaceAll": {
                        "input": "$$this",
                        "find": "user:",
                        "replacement": ""
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      // process groups entries
      groupUsers: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$permissions.users",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  0,
                  {
                    "$indexOfCP": [
                      "$$this",
                      "group:"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      "$replaceAll": {
                        "input": "$$this",
                        "find": "group:",
                        "replacement": ""
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "groups",
      "localField": "groupUsers",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "groupUsers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      // flatten and union of users for all other permissions
      "otherPermissionsUsers": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$permissions.otherPermissions",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.users"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "groupUsers": {
        // append "user:" prefix to looked up group users
        "$map": {
          "input": "$groupUsers",
          "as": "g",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$g",
              {
                users: {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$$g.users",
                    "as": "u",
                    "in": {
                      "$concat": [
                        "user:",
                        "$$u"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "users": {
        // append "user:" prefix to users
        "$map": {
          "input": "$users",
          "as": "u",
          "in": {
            "$concat": [
              "user:",
              "$$u"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      resource: 1,
      permissions: {
        permission: 1,
        // flatten and union users and looked up groups
        users: {
          "$setUnion": [
            "$users",
            {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$groupUsers",
                "initialValue": [],
                "in": {
                  "$setUnion": [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                      "$setDifference": [
                        "$$this.users",
                        "$otherPermissionsUsers"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      resource: {
        $first: "$resource"
      },
      permissions: {
        $push: "$permissions"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hfBwEa7X8_y)

Comment: Thanks @ray. This is close but, and this is probably my fault for not describing what I'm looking for well enough, the result has `user:abc` in both the `role:documentOwner` permission and the `document.read` permission. What I'm looking for is `user:abc` to only be in the `document.read` permission since they were explicitly defined for `resource:docs/61`.

Comment: @bflemi3 sorry for misunderstanding it again. updated the answer to store the other users in other permissions and use it for later pruning

Comment: This is impressive. You're good 